# How to control the D-Bus daemon virtual memory usage?

Tags: virtual-memory, d-bus, memory-leaks

I am currently trying the D-Bus sample codes from the following link:

https://linoxide.com/how-tos/d-bus-ipc-mechanism-linux/

It worked.

Then I performed the exhaustion tests on the sample code above i.e., broadcast the DBus messages rapidly to other DBus users, who did not handle the received message as quick as the sender sent them, the D-Bus daemon's virtual memory usage started to grow, which is expected as DBus daemon's outgoing queue accumulated.

Then I stopped the sender process, the D-Bus daemon's virtual memory usage should start to shrink as the receiver is disseminating the message with the filter function. However, the D-Bus daemon's virtual memory usage did not shrink down even after the receiver process completed disseminating all the data.

I have tried the above tests for the following three cases:

1. sender application broadcasted the messages to all receiver applications via DBus.
2. sender application sent the method call messages to a particular receiver application, without requesting a reply
3. sender application sent the method call messages to a particular receiver application, requesting a reply from receiver application.
   case 1 and 2 will make the dbus daemon virtual memory usage enlarge and its virtual memory usage would not shrink if the sender application were terminated and the receiver application completed the handlings of all messages from sender.

Case 3, however, would not have the DBus daemon VM usage grown. The VM usage remained unchanged during the test.

So my question is, how to make the case 1 and 2 behave as case 3? Or alternatively, even though the VM usage grew due to the message queues in DBus daemon, its VM usage should shrink down to its original state after the receiver applications completed disseminating all the incoming messages.

I doubt that DBus daemon should have some configurations to set so that it can release these memory usage after the receiver application completed handling these messages. I have spent quite a while looking for such a configuration in the DBus daemon config file (for session bus) in the following link:

https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html

But I cannot find any of those in the page above. So Please advise how I can make dbus daemon to release these VM usages after the messages have been handled?

PS: the linux command I used to check the VM usage of the dbus daemon is:

```
cat /proc/`pgrep dbus-daemon | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`/status | grep Vm
```